# How to handle correlated FX properties?

Tags: java, properties, javafx-8

Properties - ol' style bean properties just the same as blinky fx properties - work best if they are orthogonal to each other. They pose problems - again, both types - if they are somehow correlated. Which might happen in nasty Real World more often than we like.

As an example take the twosome selectedIndex/selectedItem: the index points to the position of the item in a list if it is contained, or is negative if not. Updating one requires to update the other as well.

For java beans, the solution is [straightforward](https://github.com/kleopatra/swingempire-fx/wiki/Correlated-Properties) because the bean itself has full control about when to fire the changes. And for fx beans?

A base pattern used in SelectionModel

```
Property<T> theRealItemProperty = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
ReadOnlyProperty<T> readOnlyItemProperty = new ReadOnlyObjectProperty(theRealItemProperty);
/**
 * Public access is read-only
 */
public final ReadOnlyProperty<T> itemProperty() {
    return readOnlyItemProperty;
}
/**
 *  Setting allowed for subclasses only (and mis-behaving package neighbors ;-)
 */
protected final void setItem(T item) {
    theRealItemProperty.set(item);
}
/**
 * Special setting api for general public
 */
public void select(T item) {
   setIndex(indexOf(item));
   setItem(item);
}
```

The properties fire at the time of calling their setters, the bean has no control. As internal state is unstable between those calls, listeners to the first must not access the second on receiving the notification .. as they can’t know which is the first to fire, they cannot rely on the bean being stable, ever.

What to do now, either on owning bean or client side? Somehow defer the fire? The ol' trick Platform.runLater() scattered all over application code? Stumped ..

Comment: SelectionModel in this form is a bad idea anyhow, since it forces an integer based model underneath. Basically this should have been only one property. For example: my JFXtras CalendarPicker would love to implement SelectionModel, but since it has no notion of an integer, it can't.

That said, the fundamental issue of correlated properties is not solved with that remark. Maybe they should have a "postpone event" method.

Comment: @tbeernot don't get me started on SelectionModel ;-) Thanks for the comment, had been thinking along similar lines (to no avail, though)

Comment: Tomas Mikula addresses this as part of his [ReactFX](https://github.com/TomasMikula/ReactFX/wiki/InhiBeans) framework.

Comment: @James_D thanks for the reference! Not yet looked at the code, but stumbled about "invalidation listeners are executed in the order they were registered" in the description - sounds like an assumption/implementation detail to me or is notification sequence specified somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by James_D, [ReactFX' InhiBeans](https://github.com/TomasMikula/ReactFX/wiki/InhiBeans) come to the rescue.

When coding a bean from scratch, use the properties provided by that package - they extend core classes, have the same names so its as simple as exchanging the imports. Then guard modifying methods like:

```
public void select(T item) {
   Guard guard = Guard.multi(theRealItemProperty.guard(), 
       theRealIndexProperty.guard());
   setIndex(indexOf(item));
   setItem(item);
   guard.close();
}
```

When subclassing core classes that finalized their correlated properties an option might be to go dirty: replace them via reflection. An example is [AbstractSelectionModelBase](https://github.com/kleopatra/swingempire-fx/tree/master/fx8-swingempire/src/java/de/swingempire/fx/scene/control/selection) which currently is the base MultipleSelectionModel in my experiments

```
// going dirty: replace super's selectedItem/Index property 
// with guarded cousins 
itemReplacement = new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(this, "selectedItem");
replaceField("selectedItem", itemReplacement);
indexReplacement = new ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper(this, "selectedIndex", -1);
replaceField("selectedIndex", indexReplacement);

// usage in methods that update single selection state
protected void syncSingleSelectionState(int selectedIndex) {
    Guard guard = Guard.multi(itemReplacement.guard(), indexReplacement.guard());
    setSelectedIndex(selectedIndex);
    if (selectedIndex > -1) {
        setSelectedItem(getModelItem(selectedIndex));
    } else {
        // PENDING JW: do better? can be uncontained item
        setSelectedItem(null);
    } 
    guard.close();
    focus(selectedIndex);
}
```

Would be cool to have (and use it!) such a feature in core.

Comment: I don't see a way to improve on that (others might...). When working with a selection model, I basically avoid interacting with both the `selectedIndexProperty` and the `selectedItemProperty`. Specifically, if I need only the item (usual case), I use the `selectedItemProperty`. If I need the index I use the `selectedIndexProperty` and then refer back to the originating list if I need both (i.e. `T item = listView.getItems().get(listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());`). Similar issues arise in cell implementations with `indexProperty` and `itemProperty`.

Comment: @James_D yeah, selectionModel meant just as an example. Maybe the only way out (without core support along the lines of reactfx) is being aware of which properties might be correlated (it's not always as obvious as here) and defensively code against the worst always.

Comment: This basically is the postpone approach.